# HTML Select Input & jquery change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to update a div as response of a select input change. I've tried .change but .mouseup and .click seems to be the only ones working, but only for chrome on windows.

```
<script>
$('#sel').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'value') {
       $('.response').html('You have selected value');
   } else {
       $('.response').html('You have selected the wrong value, try again');
   }
})
</script>
```

I also tried `.on('change', function()` but nothing.

Comment: how about `$(document).on('change','#sel',function(){});`?

Comment: this too works `$('#sel').on('input', function(){});`

Comment: I know you have your problem sorted, but might be a good idea to follow convention and define script type as well.

Comment: If it's not really dynamic, you're probably just missing a `document.ready` wrapper.